# How to display records from database in select onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm a beginner in coding of PHP, just want to ask how to display records using the script below?

```
$option = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['rfq'].'">'.$row['rfq'].'</option>';
}   
?>
<form>
 <select> 
 <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
</form>
```

[image]

ALL option is load when the page runs and displays all the record in table, and when I choose 13-001 I want to display the record of 13-001. How to do that?

Comment: If any of the answers answered your question can you mark it please.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, dude. It's very cool and easy.

[An Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

[Another good example using jQuery](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html)

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, the OP still doesn't know how to GET the information let alone mess around with UI effects.

Comment: There are good examples of how to work with AJAX, how to get an element value, etc. If he is not good with that - I think he will ask more clearly. He has to try by himself, this is the only way to learn something. Am I wrong?

Comment: The OP still needs the base script (see below) before he can call anything in AJAX. "when I choose 13-001 I want to display the record of 13-001. How to do that?"

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't display the records, I echo the row and the result is UNDEFINED, what is the problem? I made it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ts6dD/

Comment: @dummydummy you can't use PHP on Fiddle.

Comment: yah i know, i just want to show to you what script I got. what is the problem with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing again but use a WHERE clause.
Also i hope you are using mysqli not mysql - it will be gone soon.

```
<form>
    <select name='rfq' onChange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option></option>
    etc...
    </select>
    <input name='Submit' value='Submit' type='submit'>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $rfq = $_POST['rfq'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE rfq = '$rfq'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "{$row['id']} <br>";
    echo "{$['field1']} <br>";
    echo "{$row['field2']} <br>";
    etc..
    }
}

?>
```

You need to format it of course, but that should get you started.

Comment: Ok sir I will try it.